# Shutting down Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i'm new to Spark and i have one question.

I have Spark Streaming application which uses Kafka. Is there way to tell my application to shut down if new batch is empty (let's say batchDuration = 15 min)?

Comment: Which version of Spark Streaming are you using?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin version 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Something in the lines of should do it:

```
dstream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
    if (rdd.isEmpty) {
        streamingContext.stop()
    }
}
```

But be aware that depending on your application workflow, it could be that the first batch (or some batch in between) is also empty and hence your job will stop on the first run. You may need to combine some conditions for a more reliable stop.